# How to install GitLab Runner on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab-runner

I have downloaded the package for the system:

```
curl -LJO "https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/deb/gitlab-runner_${arch}.deb"
```

And then installed the package on my server(system), with this command:

```
dpkg -i gitlab-runner_<arch>.deb
```

When i run this command on my server i get this error:

```
bash: arch: No such file or directory
```

How can i solve this? (For what reason i get this?)

Comment: Are you literally running `dpkg -i gitlab-runner_<arch>.deb`? You're supposed to replace `<arch>` with your system's architecture, like for example `amd64`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace ${arch} with any of the supported architectures, e.g. amd64, arm, arm64

e.g. amd64 for x86 arch base systems.

Your request should look like below.

curl -LJO "https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/deb/gitlab-runner_amd64.deb"

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html